# Are there router or other network settings that can prevent the setting of a static IP addresson a client PC

Tags: arp

We need to set up an application that requires the client PC to have a static IP address. It was having trouble retaining the assigned IP address between reboots until we disabled Gratuitous ARP.

We have set this application up on numerous networks and never encountered this problem.  Is there a setting i.e. on the router or DNS that might be reassigning the IP address?

Comment: Since you did not mention the operating system it's hard to answer accurately, but gratuitous arp is sometime use to detect IP address conflict. So there's luck you set an IP address that was already use elsewhere on the network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a setting i.e. on the router or DNS that might be reassigning the IP address?

DNS doesn't assign IP address. Neither do routers unless they are providing a DHCP service (assuming IPv4). DHCP is the service on the network that provides IP addresses, whether that is on a server, a router or some other device.

> Are there router or other network settings that can prevent the setting of a static IP address on a client PC?

As for features that can create problems like this, there are a number of them including dynamic ARP incpection (DAI), IP source guard, or any other feature that requires the use of DHCP for hosts to operate on the network properly.

However, just disabling gratuitous ARP won't typically cause a difference in how those features work. So maybe something like an ARP rate limit may be in play.

Ultimately, your simple question of are there such features, we can answer. Telling you which and why they are working as you describe would take much more information (vendor/models of devices, diagrams, configurations, packet captures, etc).

Comment: The OS on the client is Windows 7 Embedded. The router is Cisco but I don't know the model. Are the settings mentioned such as "dynamic ARP incpection (DAI), IP source guard, or any other feature that requires the use of DHCP for hosts to operate on the network properly" set at the router or other network component, or are these settings done within the client?

Comment: These are features that are implemented on the newtork, typically on switches but could include other platforms as well.